# Serializar objeto NHibernate para JSON

Tags: c#, json, nhibernate

Como eu posso serializar um objeto NHibernate para JSON.
Quando eu tento serializar da erro dizendo que não é possível serializar um objeto no contexto.

Comment: Qual método você está usando para serializar? Qual a mensagem completa do erro? Posta código e print pra ajudar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui serializar, acredito que deveria ser por que no mapeamento estava com Lazy habilitado, coloquei os carregamentos Lazy para false e deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não deve serializar um objeto de domínio. Você deve sempre carregar seu objeto de domínio, com o NHibernate por exemplo, e transforma-lo num ViewModel, ou seja, em uma representação desse objeto para determinada chamada.

Se você serializa um objeto de domínio, o serializador vai passar por todas as propriedades do seu objeto, inclusive listas, você corre um risco enorme de se deparar com um erro de referência cíclica ao serializar. Abaixo um exemplo:

```
public class Cliente
{
   public List<Pedido> Pedidos {get;set;}
}

public class Pedido
{
   public Cliente Cliente {get;set;
}
```

Se você carregar um Cliente e serializar o objeto cliente, ele ira serializar também a lista de Pedido e cada objeto pedido terá a referencia do Cliente, que será serializado também. Isso entra em loop, é chamado de referência cíclica.